# Recursive CTE to join on partition date column to save on memory consumption

Tags: hive

I have a table A with columns ID, date , col1, col2. I want to join this table to a much bigger table B with date(partition), ID, colx, coly. I want to join via date and ID.

The issue is table A contains dates ranging over a few years so if I use inner join on ID and date, the memory consumption shoots up as there is a few million records for each month in table B.

Is there any way to split the task in a recursive way as I do not wish to hardcode any dates?

Thanks!